# Why 'Unable to execute JS call: __fbBatchedBirdge is undefined in React native?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I pulled a React Native project from github and attempted to do `react-native run-ios` but I got the following error:

[image]

What could be causing this problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In RN versions < .30 this error sometimes comes up when you try to run the app in development/debug mode in xcode but use the release `jsLocation` line in `AppDelegate.m` (i.e. the offline bundle).

The solution is to use the development `jsLocation` and comment out the prod `jsLocation` or just upgrade RN to a version >= .30 where you no longer have to manually specify the dev/release `jsLocation`.

**RN version < 0.30 - AppDelegate.m**

Comment this line

```
jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];
```

Uncomment this line

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

Comment: FYI, I am using a RN version > 0.30 and still have this problem.